# Update statement in Oracle with joins

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the below code in SQL Server:

```
UPDATE RH SET
--SELECT RH.economic_class ,
economic_class = C.economic_class
FROM dbo.tblRecHist RH
JOIN tblComp C ON RH.company_id = C.company_id
WHERE RH.company_id = @CompID
AND RH.rec_date = @RecDate
```

Which I have converted in Oracle to:

```
UPDATE tblRecHist 
SET economic_class = (Select C.economic_class from tblComp C join tblRecHist 
RH  on RH.company_id = C.company_id)
WHERE RH.company_id = v_CompID
AND RH.rec_date = v_RecDate;
```

As this is a part of a big procedure I am unable to execute this independently.
So, my question is are both the logic correct? If not, what could be the possible change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That logic won't work becuase your subquery will return more than one record.  Instead of joining `tblRecHist` into your subquery, omit it and correlate the subquery with the current row of `tblRecHist` from the `UPDATE`.

```
UPDATE tblRecHist rh
SET economic_class = (Select C.economic_class 
                      from   tblComp C 
                      WHERE  C.company_id = RH.company_id )
WHERE RH.company_id = v_CompID
AND RH.rec_date = v_RecDate;
```

This assumes `company_id` is a unique key in `tblComp`.